# Four table join with fixed table construct

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to achieve what I think is an inner join with four tables in Oracle.  Here is the scenario:

Tables:

```
Course
Course_ID | Title

Course_Offering
Offering_ID | Location | Course_ID

Attendance
Student_ID | Offering_ID 

Student
Student_ID | Name | Number etc.
```

I am trying to write a query that will display just the **student_name** and **title** of the courses which a student has attended. A student can attend many offerings of a course which are stored in the `Attendance` table.  How would I go about accomplishing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select s.student, c.title
from student s, attendance a, course_offering co, course c
where s.student_id  = a.student_id
and   a.offering_id = co.offering_id
and   co.course_id  = c.course_id
and   s.student_id = "insert id here";
```

This will give you what you are looking for as long as you know the student's ID.

Comment: Using `JOIN` syntax is preferred over implicit joins.